# Estimated probability looks too large, what I am doing wrong?

Tags: probability, statistics

A factory produces links for heavy metal chains. The research lab of the factory
models the length (in cm) of a link by the random variable ${X}$, with expected
value ${E(X) = 5}$ and variance ${Var(X) = 0.04}$. The length of a link is defined
in such a way that the length of a chain is equal to the sum of the lengths of its
links. The factory sells chains of 50 meters; to be on the safe side 1002 links are
used for such chains. The factory guarantees that the chain is not shorter than 50
meters. If by chance a chain is too short, the customer is reimbursed, and a new
chain is given for free.

Give an estimate of the probability that for a chain of at least 50 meters
more than 1002 links are needed. For what percentage of the chains does
the factory have to reimburse clients and provide free chains?

---

Number of links in a chain: ${n = 1002}$

Mean lengh of 1002 links: ${ \mu = 1002 \times 0.05 = 50.1 }$

We know variance, so we can find the standard deviation: ${ \sigma = \sqrt{0.04} = 0.2 }$

We are interested how often chain is shorter then 50 meters: ${ \bar{x} = 50 }$

Thus let define an appropriate test statistic: ${ \displaystyle z = \frac{ \mu - \bar{x} }{ \sigma } = \frac{50.1 - 50}{0.2} = \frac{0.1}{0.2} = 0.5 }$

Probability of getting value in a lower tail is: ${ \displaystyle P(z < 0.5) = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int\limits_{0}^{0.5} e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}} dz }$

By making the substitution ${ z = \sqrt{2} x }$, we get:  ${ \displaystyle \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int\limits_{0}^{0.5} e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}} dz = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int\limits_{0}^{\frac{0.5}{\sqrt{2}}} e^{-x^2} dx }$

As we can not solve integral above, let's consider ${ e^{-x^2} }$ as a Taylor series: ${ \displaystyle \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n x^{2n}}{n!} }$

Then the approximate probability is: ${ \displaystyle P(z < 0.5) = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n (\frac{c}{\sqrt{2}})^{2n+1} }{ n! (2n+1) } \simeq 0.691462 }$

---

But this probability looks too large. What I am doing wrong?